# OpenVPN Disable TLS

Tags: ssl, openvpn

Since a week I'm trying to launch an "OpenVPN Access Server" on Ubuntu 18.04 but after very long study and iteration I found out my ISP is blocking TLS packets regardless of the port I use.
This conclusion is based on the observation that with different ISPs (client side) I get different results...
I tried to disable TLS with these commands:

```
cd /usr/local/openvpn_as/scripts
./sacli --key "vpn.client.cipher" --value none ConfigPut
./sacli --key "vpn.server.cipher" --value none ConfigPut
./sacli start
```

and also disabled TLS authentication in "Advanced VPN" settings.
But apparently it is not enough and there is still a residual trace of TLS packets in my communication that lets my ISP detect them and interrupt authentication...
Not only because the authentication freezes and ends, but also there are some TLS related phrases in logs:

```
21:55:35.553 -- ----- OpenVPN Start -----

21:55:35.553 -- EVENT: CORE_THREAD_ACTIVE

21:55:35.559 -- Frame=512/2048/512 mssfix-ctrl=1250

21:55:35.563 -- UNUSED OPTIONS
11 [sndbuf] [100000] 
12 [rcvbuf] [100000] 
14 [verb] [3] 
24 [CLI_PREF_ALLOW_WEB_IMPORT] [True] 
25 [CLI_PREF_BASIC_CLIENT] [False] 
26 [CLI_PREF_ENABLE_CONNECT] [True] 
27 [CLI_PREF_ENABLE_XD_PROXY] [True] 
28 [WSHOST] [X.X.184.124:1398] 
29 [WEB_CA_BUNDLE] [-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- MIIDBDCCAeygAwIBAgIEXOWA4DANBgkqhkiG...] 
30 [IS_OPENVPN_WEB_CA] [1] 
31 [ORGANIZATION] [OpenVPN, Inc.] 


21:55:35.567 -- EVENT: RESOLVE

21:55:35.570 -- Contacting X.X.184.124:1398 via TCP

21:55:35.570 -- EVENT: WAIT

21:55:35.837 -- Connecting to [X.X.184.124]:1398 (X.X.184.124) via TCPv4

21:55:36.023 -- EVENT: CONNECTING

21:55:36.027 -- Tunnel Options:V4,dev-type tun,link-mtu 1528,tun-mtu 1500,proto TCPv4_CLIENT,comp-lzo,keydir 1,cipher [null-cipher],auth SHA1,keysize 0,tls-auth,key-method 2,tls-client

21:55:36.028 -- Creds: Username/PasswordEmpty

21:55:36.029 -- Peer Info:
IV_GUI_VER=OC30Android
IV_VER=3.2
IV_PLAT=android
IV_NCP=2
IV_TCPNL=1
IV_PROTO=2
IV_LZO=1
IV_LZO_SWAP=1
IV_LZ4=1
IV_LZ4v2=1
IV_COMP_STUB=1
IV_COMP_STUBv2=1
IV_AUTO_SESS=1


21:55:36.219 -- VERIFY OK : depth=1
cert. version     : 3
serial number     : 5C:E5:80:DF
issuer name       : CN=OpenVPN CA
subject name      : CN=OpenVPN CA
issued  on        : 2019-05-15 17:03:27
expires on        : 2029-05-19 17:03:27
signed using      : RSA with SHA-256
RSA key size      : 2048 bits
basic constraints : CA=true


21:55:36.220 -- VERIFY OK : depth=0
cert. version     : 3
serial number     : 01
issuer name       : CN=OpenVPN CA
subject name      : CN=OpenVPN Server
issued  on        : 2019-05-15 17:03:27
expires on        : 2029-05-19 17:03:27
signed using      : RSA with SHA-256
RSA key size      : 2048 bits
basic constraints : CA=false
cert. type        : SSL Server


21:55:40.866 -- EVENT: DISCONNECTED

21:55:40.878 -- EVENT: CORE_THREAD_INACTIVE

21:55:40.879 -- Tunnel bytes per CPU second: 0

21:55:40.879 -- ----- OpenVPN Stop -----
```

PLZ look at the log @ 21:55:36.027

Any Idea how to disable TLS so that there are no trace of TLS packets in communication?

Comment: If your ISP blocked TLS, how are you visiting this site, which also uses TLS? Try running OpenVPN on port 443.

Comment: Thanks, If it is so, how can they detect the openvpn connection in progress and block it? I tried 443/TCP with no success. Even they block OpenVPN server's web page that uses TLS enctiption

Comment: The certificate does say it is for an "OpenVPN Server" by "OpenVPN CA". Perhaps you could make a new CA and certificates with different names.

Comment: Thanks again, It looks like my problem. But I didn't get your solution, Does certificates have name? where and how should I change them?

Comment: Have a look [there](https://openvpn.net/vpn-server-resources/installing-a-valid-ssl-web-certificate-in-access-server/), specifically at the topic: **How to alter the self-signed certificate**